# How to automatically delete the key line from known_hosts when a session is closed?

Tags: linux, ssh, known-hosts

I'm working on automating a whole environment by using AWS CloudFormation and during the testing period I'm required to kill and re-create the servers very often.

The servers are configured to set their IP addresses from a dedicated pool which means that on the first time I connect to them I have to accept the host key checking (the yes/no question) and then when I delete the server and re-create it, I have to delete the server's key from the known_hosts file each time.

My question is:

Is it possible to delete the key from known_hosts automatically when I close the session? is there such a setting which I've missed?

Comment: Just as a pointer: The answer of @ptman was posted earlier and contains the same content as the one you've accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure ssh to use multiple files for the known_hosts and new entries only get added to the first, by setting that to `/dev/null` effectively they won't get saved:

```
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Combine it with your personal favourite of asking or automatically accepting unknown keys:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

You probably want to those options restricted to only (specific hosts in) your DEV environment rather than global defaults, as they will take away quite a bit of the security key checking provides so in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *.dev.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dev.example.com
    UseKeychain yes
    User hbruijn-adm
    StrictHostKeyChecking ask
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Please write one or two lines regarding the risks / disadvantages this is introducing

Comment: @gf_ You're of course right that doing so is insecure, but you can mitigate the impact somewhat as I updated above.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -l user host
```

StrictHostKeyChecking=no is of course a bad idea, since it will automatically accept all hosts keys

UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null will not save anything to your normal known_hosts file.

Comment: Please write one or two lines regarding the risks / disadvantages this is introducing.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to put the `SSHFP` (automatically) into the `DNS`, sign the zone via `DNSSEC` and let `SSH` handle the rest, especially, if you need to do this very often and the keys are changing constantly.

Comment: Will ssh(1) actually verify the DNSSEC signature in order to trust the SSHFP record or will it blindly trust the system resolver?

Comment: @ptman I think (but don't take this for granted) it will rely on the system resolver. The response needs to have the `ad` bit set.

Comment: Sure, but the interface to the resolver (res_nquery(3)?) doesn't tell ssh(1) if the ad bit was set or not, or does it?

Comment: @ptman I can't explain the inner workings: I use this myself, but didn't dig into the code. All I can say is, that it makes a difference, it the `ad` bit is set or not. Without `ad`, `SSH` will print `Matching host key fingerprint found in DNS.` and will still ask you to manually accept or decline the fingerprint.